# Synchronous motor mystery

Tags: power, motor, analog, synchronous

Not too long ago I acquired an old ('70/'80) German flip clock. I found out that this clock is driven by a one-phase synchronous engine.

I can't get the motor to run. I (carefully!) connected the motor to the mains (220V 50Hz). The results was a chaotic buzzing and the motor oscillating.
The motor look like this:

[image: The assembled synchronous motor]

I have no idea what 'Type 5' or 'BT 1200' signifies (I googled it extensively). The coil has 4 wires running from it. Counting from top to bottom, or from green to yellow, the resistance between:

- 1 and 4 (green and yellow) is 460 Ohm
- 2 and 3 are shorted (0 Ohm), not in the coil but the blue and black wire
- 1 and 3, 2 and 4 is 230 Ohm

With the coil removed the axis becomes visible:

[image: Coil removed]

One turn of the axle moves the clock forward 1 minute (I am able to turn it by hand). This is also weird. What I understood of synchronous motors is that they rotate at the same frequency as the mains it is connected to, in this case 50Hz. In other words 50 times to fast.

I can easily remove the axle as well:

[image: Axle removed]

Behind it is the gearbox. The motor is obviously not a [Shaded-pole motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaded-pole_motor).

So how does it start? Perhaps it needs a different voltage (the clock was recovered from an industrial complex)? 120V, 480V? Is there a (start) component removed? On the second image there are some protrusions visible on the left side of the axis with no obvious function.

And how to explain the difference between the expected rotational speed of the motor (50 rpm) and the required 1 rotation per minute for the clock?

Comment: This doesn't sounds like a motor to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Brave the man who connects mains voltage to a device when he is uncertain if it is intended to be mains powered.

Sometimes dead, the equipment or the experimenter, or both, become, also.
 Harm sounds like an apposite user name :-).

From what you say it now seems even more likely than before that my previous answer to [your previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31095/identify-component-in-old-west-german-flip-clock) is correct or along the rights lines, but that you are ignoring it in favour of an incorrect answer. But, I may be wrong :-).

Part of my prior answer said:

- It's effectively an electric motor - possibly driven at mains frequency and possibly an escapement release solenoid - but maybe effectively both. Probably it provides the complete driving power for the flip action but **the double lobe cam (see below) suggests triggering at regular intervals**. If there is no other timing or driving mechanism **then it may have been run as a "slave" with control pulses sent via the visible wiring from a central controller.**

and

- This mechanism may work with the same pulses used to control time clocks in older analog dial systems - used in eg British Railway Stations long ago I think - and many other such locations.

Try driving it with a 1 Hz pulse (possible square wave, possibly sinusoid) and see what happens.

---

**ADDED:**

Newly provided information makes it almost certain that this is indeed a linked system clock that shares a 1 minute pulse with other clocks. Pulse may be on briefly once per minute. Or on then reversed then off once per minutes. Or on/off, wait 30s or 1 minutes, reverse polarity, on/off etc. Stepping may be always on one polarity edge or every reversal. "Just a matter of playing" now.

Looking at that "motor" it looks like it may attract the rotor through one half rotation when energised and then another half when released or perhaps energised in the other direction. Find the ~= SMALLEST DC voltage that will step the motor. If you apply and remove this, does it rotate.
 If not, try applying with alternate polarities. Probably leave on only briefly.

If the one second pulse or some variant of it works you can produce it with a controller that is s simple as a 555 timer (bad stability) or a simple crystal and divider system, or a microcontroller etc . Discuss once you have the basic system working.

Comment: :) Right you are!

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand. There are not other timing or driving mechanisms. So what you are saying is that it needs a 1Hz control pulse. Does that mean powering the coil once ever second? (I need 1/60 Hz if 1 pulse equates to one rotation.)

Comment: @harm - Try it and see. If 1 Hz pulses work then it needs 1 Hz input. There may be some other way of driving it but this seems extremely unlikely. In large complaxes such as factories, government buildings, railway stations and similar, it was common to have clocks which were all driven from a single time keeping source by a common drive circuit running throughout the establishment. The ones I have seen (and I have one sample of) typically used 1 pulse per minute but one pulse per second may make sense if it has a seconds flipper. Your factory complex may have had such a system.

Comment: Alright. So how would I go about that? How do I generate a 1/60Hz DC(?) pulse?

Comment: Aha. One rotation per minute  / 1/60th Hz. You prior input indicated both 1 second pulses and 1 minute pulses in differnt places. You mean 1 pulse or step per minute - which aligns precisely with the linked clock systems that I described :-). Looking at that "motor" it looks like it may attract the rotor through one half rotation when energised and then another half when released or perhaps energised in the other direction. Find the ~= SMALLEST DC voltage that will step the motor. If you apply and remove, does it rotate. If not, try applying with alternate polarities. See answer addition->

Comment: Hmmm. Correct answer. Accepted. No votes. :-) . How very strange. Not that it matters or anything, but still strange.

Comment: The line frequency would typically be used for timekeeping. In this era, a [pulse detector](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=pulse+detector) could increment counter A from a sample of the line frequency (60Hz), so once for each 60 cycles per second. So counter A output is once every second. This counter would feed counter B, which also counts to 60, and it's output is once per minute. But counter output is probably static (either low or high, not a pulse) so the final piece is a [one-shot](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=one-shot) which sends a timed pulse -> coil.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same flip clock that I found from internet which has the same motor. I didn't find answers on how it works -- just that it needs a master clock. After this discussion I got a idea and tried applying 12 VDC to the motor with (Y&B) (R&W) wires as pairs.

[image: BT600 type5]

And I found that when it changes pole between red & blue draw line it will flip. So I used a 1 second pulse with a 1-minute period using an Arduino and a motor driver board L298N. Here's the program:

```
const int motor1a = 12;
const int motor1a = 13;
void setup()
{
pinMode(motor1a,OUTPUT);
pinMode(motor2a,OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
digitalWrite(motor1a,LOW);
digitalWrite(motor2a,LOW);
delay(59000);
digitalWrite(motor1a,HIGH);
digitalWrite(motor2a,LOW);
delay(1000);
digitalWrite(motor1a,LOW);
digitalWrite(motor2a,LOW);
delay(59000);
digitalWrite(motor1a,LOW);
digitalWrite(motor2a,HIGH);
delay(1000);
}
```

[image: setup]

Finally it happily worked.

Comment: This seems like the start of a good answer, in having taken the idea of it being part of a master to clock system to the point of implementing a driver.   If you could replace your screenshot with a block of text, it might merit some upvotes.